# sql- Like Query find

Tags: sql

Would anyone know what to do with this I am doing a like query to select info. example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM customers
 WHERE customer_name LIKE '26%'
```

which will return

```
26_xx
26_xx
265_xx
```

but i only want to display 26_xx

I have tried which was suggested from a site :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM customers
 WHERE customer_name LIKE 'H%!%' escape '!';
```

but that also returned

```
26_xx
26_xx
265_xx
```

Comment: For what database, and version of?

Comment: and SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_name  = '26_xx' isn't any good?

Comment: i'm suspecting this is a regular expression issue?

Comment: How do you want to determine which result to show?

Answer (score 4):

In T-SQL you can use `[]` to escape the *wildcard* character `_`;

```
SELECT * FROM customers
    WHERE customer_name LIKE '26[_]%'
```

The ESCAPE version would be;

```
SELECT * FROM customers
    WHERE customer_name LIKE '26!_%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Comment: You don't have to escape "_" do you?  You can just say LIKE '26_%', at least on my system (SQL 2008 R2)

Comment: `_` is *any character* so matches the `5` in `265_xx`

Comment: that wasn't quite right; it returned "26-22" in my below sample dataset (and I failed to notice, shame on me), but not "265_22".  Anyway I've corrected my answer below; thanks for the tip.

Comment: I think thats because your restricting to 5 chars so its not a candidate for a match

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 

FROM customers

WHERE customer_name LIKE '26_%'
```

Is this what you mean? Only where the names start "26_" or do I read your question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
WHERE customer_name LIKE '26[_]%' 
  and len(customer_name) = 5
```

Proof:

```
select
  sample_data.*
from
  (
  select '26_55' as customer_name
  union
  select '26_abc'
  union
  select '265_22'
  union
  select '26-22'
  union
  select 'abc'
  union
  select '26_18'
  ) sample_data
where sample_data.customer_name like '26[_]%'
  and len(sample_data.customer_name) = 5
```