# SQL - Finding rows with similar values for a column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 ID   NAME       Email
 1    John       john@example.com
 2    Mathew     mathew@example.com
 3    John       jon@example.com
 4    Johnson    johns@example.com
 5    Peter      pete@example.com
```

How can I create a query that will return

```
1    John       john@example.com
3    John       jon@example.com
4    Johnson    johns@example.com
```

Ansers like that for [Find rows that have the same value on a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786533/find-rows-that-have-the-same-value-on-a-column-in-mysql)  returns rows with same value. Here I need similar values

Comment: How do you define similar values?

Comment: I suppose you don't mean something like `select * from ... where NAME like 'john%'`, see: [MySQL Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)?!
Perhaps you mean something like [SQL Similar Data in Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744220/sql-similar-data-in-column)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql- Like Query find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626775/sql-like-query-find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the records with similar email first and then only print those records that match the inner condition.

```
 select * from table_name where email in   (
  select email from table_name 
  group by email 
  having count(*)>1 
)
```

Tested and working fine.